# Decrypt data from database in my Index page with EasyAdminBundle3 and Symfony5

Tags: php, encryption, event-handling, symfony5, easyadmin

I create a service to encrypt and decrypt my data in my database.
So when I create a new Fiche or update one, I encrypt the name and the surname
Here my subscriber FicheEntitySubscriber :

```php
class FicheEntitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $security;
    private $encryptionService;

    public function __construct(Security $security, EncryptionService $encryptionService)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->encryptionService = $encryptionService;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeEntityPersistedEvent::class => ['setFicheEntity', 10],
            BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent::class => ['setFicheEntity', 10]
        ];
    }

/**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function setFicheEntity(AbstractLifecycleEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();

        if (!($entity instanceof FicheEntity)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($event instanceof BeforeEntityPersistedEvent) {
            $entity->setUtilisateur($this->security->getUser());
        }

        $entity->setNom($this->encryptionService->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', mb_strtoupper($entity->getNom())));
        $entity->setPrenom($this->encryptionService->encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', mb_strtoupper($entity->getPrenom())));
       
    }
}
```

Here my FicheController :

```php
class FicheEntityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    private $_adminContextFactory;
    private $encryptService;
    private $ficheEntityRepo;

    public function __construct(AdminContextFactory $adminContextFactory, EncryptionService $encryptionService, FicheEntityRepository $ficheEntityRepo)
    {
        $this->_adminContextFactory = $adminContextFactory;
        $this->encryptService = $encryptionService;
        $this->ficheEntityRepo = $ficheEntityRepo;
    }

    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return FicheEntity::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Fiches')
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Fiche informative')
            ->setSearchFields(['nom', 'prenom', 'nomAntibio'])
            ->setPaginatorPageSize(10)
            ->setPaginatorRangeSize(2);
    }

    public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
    {
        return $filters
            ->add(TextFilter::new('nomAntibio')->setLabel('Nom ATB'))
            ->add(DateTimeFilter::new('dateDebut')->setLabel('Date Debut'))
            ->add(DateTimeFilter::new('dateRappel3Jour')->setLabel('Rappel 3e Jour'))
            ->add(DateTimeFilter::new('dateRappel7Jour')->setLabel('Rappel 7e Jours'));
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        $export = Action::new('exportAction', 'Export')
            ->setIcon('fa fa-download')
            ->linkToCrudAction('exportAction')
            ->setCssClass('btn')
            ->createAsGlobalAction();

        return $actions
            ->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $export);
    }

    public function exportAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $context = $this->_getEasyAdminRefererContext($request);

        $searchDto = $this->_adminContextFactory->getSearchDto($request, $context->getCrud());
        $fields = FieldCollection::new($this->configureFields(Crud::PAGE_INDEX));
        $filters = $this->get(FilterFactory::class)->create($context->getCrud()->getFiltersConfig(), $fields, $context->getEntity());


        $result = $this->createIndexQueryBuilder(
            $searchDto, $context->getEntity(), $fields, $filters
        )
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        $data = [];
        /**
         * @var $record FicheEntity
         */
        foreach ($result as $record) {
            $data[] = [
                'Nom Complet' => $record->getFullname(),
                'Chambre' => $record->getChambre(),
                'Date Debut' => $record->getDateDebut()->format('y-m-d'),
                'Duree ATB' => $record->getDureeJour(),
                'Nom ATB' => $record->getNomAntibio(),
                'Rappel 3e Jour' => ($record->getDateRappel3Jour() !== null ? $record->getDateRappel3Jour()->format('y-m-d') : $record->getDateRappel3Jour()),
                'Réévalué' => ($record->getDateRappel3Jour() !== null ? ($record->getReevalue() === true ? 'oui' : 'non') : ''),
                'Rappel 7e Jour' => ($record->getDateRappel7Jour() !== null ? $record->getDateRappel7Jour()->format('y-m-d') : $record->getDateRappel7Jour()),
                'Justifié' => ($record->getDateRappel7Jour() !== null ? ($record->getJustifie() === true ? 'oui' : 'non') : ''),
                'Pathologie' => $record->getPathologie(),
                'Hospitalier' => ($record->getHospitalier() === true ? 'oui' : '')
            ];

        }

        $filename = 'export_fiche_' . date_create()->format('d-m-y H:i:s') . '.csv';

        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new CsvEncoder()]);
        $response = new Response($serializer->encode($data, CsvEncoder::FORMAT));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");

        return $response;
    }

    private function _getEasyAdminRefererContext(Request $request)
    {

        \parse_str(\parse_url($request->query->get(EA::REFERRER))[EA::QUERY], $referrerQuery);
        if (array_key_exists(EA::FILTERS, $referrerQuery)) {
            $request->query->set(EA::FILTERS, $referrerQuery);
        }

        return $request->attributes->get(EA::CONTEXT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE);
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            IntegerField::new('id')->hideOnForm()->hideOnIndex(),
            TextField::new('nom')->hideOnIndex()->setColumns(6),
            TextField::new('prenom')->hideOnIndex()->setColumns(6),
            TextField::new('fullname')->setLabel('Nom complet')->hideOnForm(),
            IntegerField::new('chambre')->setColumns(4),
            TextField::new('nomAntibio')->setLabel('Nom ATB')->setColumns(4),
            IntegerField::new('dureeJour')->setLabel('Durée ATB TTT')->setColumns(4),
            DateField::new('dateDebut'),
            DateField::new('dateRappel3Jour')->setLabel('Rappel 3e Jour')->hideOnForm(),
            BooleanField::new('reevalue')->setLabel('Réévalué')->hideOnForm(),
            DateField::new('dateRappel7Jour')->setLabel('Rappel 7e Jour')->hideOnForm(),
            BooleanField::new('justifie')->setLabel('Justifié')->hideOnForm(),
            TextField::new('pathologie'),
            AssociationField::new('utilisateur', 'Admin')->setLabel('Utilisateur')->hideOnForm(),
            BooleanField::new('hospitalier')

        ];
    }
```

My issue is that when I display my list of fiches, I want to decrypt the encrypted data, for now I try :

- use the AfterEntityBuiltEvent (did not working)
- listen on Event postLoad
- create an custom action

but none of these are working. Does someone try something similar ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't help your current situation, but we use [this for Encryption with Symfony](https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle) because it allows us to use `@Encrypted` on our entities. We've brought it to [PHP 8 here](https://github.com/vendi-advertising/doctrine-encrypt-bundle), too. The encryption is transparent to the application, too, regardless of Easy Admin or custom. You might be able to poke through that to see the details of how it works, too.

Comment: The problem will be still the same even with the bundle. Because even if you encrypt your data in the database with the bundle once you want to display in EasyAdmin, how do you decrypt them in the crud controller ? Am I right ?

Comment: Like I said, it is a transparent encryption, you read and write raw, but it is stored encrypted

Comment: Well I try it this morning. I use composer/require, create a config file **config/encrypt.yml**, I create .HaliteEncryptor.key in root and put value like 994441c882e862f9135edd656de299 in it and then use annotation in my entity. I try to register a client, so I see in my admin page the plain value, but in my database I see also the plain value and not encrypted

Comment: I use composer/require  **"michaeldegroot/doctrine-encrypt-bundle"**